# XML filter from a select box

Tags: xml, selenium

Does maybe someone know how to filter a XML tree for this selected value? I need the "B3" String for another use in Selenium.

Would be great if someone could help me. :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

It's a static drop down, the values are not gonna change.

Please use

```
//option[@value='1' and @selected]
```

also, you could use

```
//option[@value='1' and @selected and text()='B3']
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Update :**

```
List<WebElement> dropDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='wert_1']//option");
try{
    for (WebElement option  : dropDown)
        if (option.getAttribute('selected').contains('selected')){
            System.out.println("Selected option is "+ option.getAttribute('innerText'))
        }
        else
            System.out.println("none of the options are selected")
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("something went wrong")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers always cruisepandey, I rly appreciate it!

yes I know this tricks with the dev tools and to export the XPath. The Problem is that i wanna save the choosen or Selected Attribute from this static dropdown menu to handle it later.. Isn't there any query to filter for this 'selected' attribute? unfortunately I'm not very experienced with this xml querys..

Comment: I couldn't understand your question properly. Did you mean to say you would want to verify which is the selected option in this drop down ?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to figure out at runtime which option is choosen..

Comment: If you are using python, please see above updated code.

Comment: Unfortunately i‘m using Java but thanks for the code! :)

Comment: @Andreas :  Updated above in Java, Please see above

Comment: Can we close this ticket if it worked for you ?

Comment: hadn't time to try it in the morning.. but it doesn't work..the list gets a length of 35 and also the first if query isn't working because this isn't a boolean expression.. :/

Comment: You probably can have it like this `if (option.getAttribute('selected').contains('selected'))`, it should help you by past the issue.

Comment: it let me run immediately into the catch condition..

Comment: Then issue is here `//select[@name='wert_1']//option`, make sure it is representing the right drop down.

Comment: also if the right xpath is selected, it gives me just 1 value back in the list haha.. but nvm, now I found another field which represent this selected values.. this select boxes makes me crazy :D but thanks a lot for your patience and effort :D u're the best :D

Comment: How many nodes does it represent in HTMLDOM ? in dev tools ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237839/discussion-between-andreas-and-cruisepandey).